# Laravel - Group By & Key By together

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

Assuming I have the following MySQL tables to represent pricebooks, items and the relationship between them:

```
item - item_id|name|...etc
pricebook - pricebook_id|name|...etc
```

and the following `pivot table`

```
pricebook_item - pricebook_id|item_id|price|...etc
```

I have the correlating Eloquent models: `Pricebook`, `Item` and a repository named `PricebookData` to retrieve the necessary information.

Within the `PricebookData` repository, I need to get the pricebook data grouped by pricebook id and then keyed by item_id for easy access on client side.

If I do:

```
Pricebook::all()->groupBy('pricebook_id');
```

I get the information grouped by the `pricebook_id` but inside each pricebook the keys are simple numeric index (it arrives as js array) and not the actual product_id. So when returning to client side Javascript, the result arrives as the following:

```
pricebookData: {1: [{}, {}, {}...], 2: [{}, {}, {}...]}
```

The problem with the prices arriving as array, is that I can not access it easily without iterating the array. Ideally I would be able to receive it as:

```
 pricebookData: {1: {1001:{}, 1002: {}, 1003: {}}, 2: {1001:{}, 1002: {}, 1003: {}}}
//where 1001, 1002, 1003 are actual item ids
//with this result format, I could simply do var price = pricebookData[1][1001]
```

I've also tried the following but without success:

`Pricebook::all()->keyBy('item_id')->groupBy('pricebook_id');`

The equivalent of what I am trying to avoid is:

```
$prices = Pricebook::all();
$priceData = [];
foreach ($prices as $price) 
{
   if (!isset($priceData[$price->pricebook_id])) 
   {
      $priceData[$price->pricebook_id] = [];
   }
   $priceData[$price->pricebook_id][$price->item_id] = $price;
}
return $priceData;
```

I am trying to find a pure elegant Eloquent/Query Builder solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
Pricebook::all()
    ->groupBy('pricebook_id')
    ->map(function ($pb) { return $pb->keyBy('item_id'); });
```

You first group by Pricebook, then each Pricebook subset is keyed by item_id. You were on the right track with

```
Pricebook::all()->keyBy('item_id')->groupBy('pricebook_id');
```

unfortunately, as it is implemented, the `groupBy` resets previous keys.

#### Update:

```
Pricebook::all()->keyBy('item_id')->groupBy('pricebook_id', true);
```

(`groupBy` second parameter `$preserveKeys`)

Comment: Thank you for the update. It's great to know that this parameter exist but actually doesn't work as expected at all, when $preserveKeys is true it messes the result completely and somehow merges both the groupBy keys and the keyBy keys, which results in an unexpected object.

Comment: I see.. Ok, so the first suggestion did work, right?

Comment: It did, not entirely what I was hoping for but will be marked as right answer if I can't find a way to make keyBy & groupBy work together....Thanks!